# Issue when using escaped forward slashes "//" in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I am creating a script to insert JSON object into mongo DB.

when I use Document doc = Document.parse("{\"basePath\": \"http:11.223.107.226:9002\"}"); // No forward slashes after http:

The script runs without any error. But as soon as I add slashes "//" i.e {"basePath": "http://http:11.223.107.226:9002"}

The exception I am getting is:

2022-09-27 03:08:17,435 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script3.groovy: 18: Unexpected character: '"' @ line 18, column 31.
Document doc = Document.parse("{\"basePath\": \"http:\/\/11.223.107.226:9002\"}");
^

1 error

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:183) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:211) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:968) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:585) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to escape the slashes, they're not on the [meta characters list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

[image]

So just use

```
Document doc = Document.parse("{\"basePath\": \"http://11.223.107.226:9002\"}");
```

or even go for [single quoted string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_single_quoted_string) for better readability, in this case you won't need to escape the quotation marks:

```
Document doc = Document.parse('{"basePath": "http://11.223.107.226:9002"}');
```

More information: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance)